# where is the command roscd

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ROS from source successfully and the command `roscd` works as expected.

Now I want to execute `roscd` in a bash script but get the error: `roscd: not found`

I've tried to find the command `roscd` but I got nothing: the output of `find / -name roscd` is empty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291603/where-is-the-command-roscd/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you completed the installation instructions? Namely, the [environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) section? From that section

> It's convenient if the ROS environment variables are automatically added to your bash session every time a new shell is launched:

> ```
> echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```

Just make sure to change the `kinetic` portion to whatever version you installed.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-18**:
Note: @jayess links to the regular (ie: binary) installation instructions, but environment setup is shared between from-source and binary installations.